# Problem finding office DCOM in Component Services in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, excel-2007, office-2007, component-services

I have a problem getting my word and excel to work in ASP .NET.

I get the error message:
**{System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005. at xxx.Utility.WordDocument..ctor(String filePath, HttpServerUtility util) at customer_communication.BuCreate_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in**

This means I have access problem to the DCOM files. In Vista this isnt a problem, all I have to do there is to run "dcomcnfg" and in there find the Microsoft Excel dcom file.

In Windows 7 I cant find it, and I have no idea what to do now...

If anyone could help me that would be great!

Comment: What edition of Windows 7 are you using? I have Ultimate and dcomcnfg seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't think that running Office in a server mode is a good idea, you can find the Win7 equivalent of dcomncfg as 'Component Services', which is a MMC plugin (comexp.msc).